# Pipeline input not being validated when a function emits no output down the pipeline for ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName parameters

Tags: powershell

I was able to reproduce this in a more generic way, and the issue is different than originally presented. I have rewritten this  question to reflect the issue experienced along with a generic reproducible example.

---

I have a cmdlet that sometimes produces no output when it doesn't find any data to return. However, I use this function to pass information to another cmdlet which accepts pipeline input via way of the `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` attribute. When there is an actual object being passed down the pipeline, everything works as expected, including parameter validation checks. However, if the passed object is `$null`, then parameter validation gets skipped. Note that this is not reproduceable when simply passing `$null` down the pipeline; I've only been able to reproduce this when emitting **no output** down the pipeline.

I've been able to reproduce this generically. The parameters are defined with the same attributes as my real code:

```
Function Get-InfoTest {
  Param(
    [switch]$ReturnNothing
  )

  if( !$ReturnNothing ) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
      Name = 'Bender'
      Age = [int]::MaxValue
    }
  }
}

Function Invoke-InfoTest {
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [string]$Name,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [int]$Age
  )

  Write-Host "Hello, $Name. I see you are $Age years old."
}

# With valid object
Get-InfoTest | Invoke-InfoTest


# Correct behavior when $null is directly passed into the cmdlet, throws error
$null | Invoke-InfoTest

# With returned null object, should throw an error but executes with an incorrect result
Get-InfoTest -ReturnNothing | Invoke-InfoTest
```

What is going on here? While it's not difficult to write null-or-whitespace checks in the function body, this is the point of the `Mandatory` parameter option as well as the `Validate*` parameter attributes. In my real code, I now need to write null-or-whitespace checks for several parameters which already have validation attributes set. As stated in the code comments, passing `$null` into the target cmdlet results in the correct error being thrown, but no output produced from a function results in the function executing as if everything was provided correctly.

Comment: I think this is expected Bender, since the feeding function is returning `AutomationNull.Value` the receiving function is never executed. For example, note the difference between `$null | ForEach-Object { 'hello' }` and `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value | ForEach-Object { 'hello' }` // or `& { } | ForEach-Object { 'hello' }` <= same as auto null

Comment: "The receiving function is never executed" - @SantiagoSquarzon What? The problem is that the receiving function *is* being executed. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean?

Comment: You're right, my bad, the __`end` block__ of the receiving function is executed but if you put your `Write-Host` statement in the __`process` block__ you would see what I tried to say. Since this is a pipeline function there would be nothing to process

Comment: Ah, maybe that is the solution then? Putting my function body in a defined `process` block, I mean.

Comment: Indeed, since your function is meant to receive objects from pipeline, it would make sense to use the logic in the `process` block else nothing would work :)

Comment: TBH that was a misunderstanding on my part. For some reason I had it in my head that function bodies defaulted to a `process` block, not `end`.

Comment: Oh yes I do understand where you're coming from, I got that misunderstanding too. Functions without blocks default to `end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't define `begin`/`process`/`end` blocks, functions bodies default to an `end` block. However, putting the function body in an explicit `process` block results in the correct behavior:

The following modification to `Invoke-InfoTest` results in the sample code working correctly for all cases:

```
Function Invoke-InfoTest {
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [string]$Name,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [int]$Age
  )

  # Note that I've wrapped this in a process block
  process {
    Write-Host "Hello, $Name. I see you are $Age years old."
  }
}
```

This works because as stated above, functions default to an `end` block if unspecified. However, the `end` and `begin` blocks are executed regardless of the pipeline object being input. `process` only gets executed when there is data passed in. Defining the code using the pipeline variables inside of a `process` block effectively stops the code using the missing data from being executed, which seems to be by design.

Thanks to [@SantiagoSquarzon in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72885426/pipeline-input-not-being-validated-when-a-function-emits-no-output-down-the-pipe?noredirect=1#comment128736290_72885426) for helping me realize the actual problem.